# VB.NET 2022 compile fails because it cannot copy the application.dll file

Tags: vb.net, compilation

Occasionally the compile process for my application CRMS fails with the message below.  I have to restart Visual Studio to rectify.  Sometimes this happens any number of times I compile since the previous reload, often in the single digits, which gets quite annoying.  How do I remedy?[image]Environment: Windows 10 Home, build 19045.3086, project is on local non-shared drive, only one instance of VS running and nothing else that should be involved.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Report a problem with the Visual Studio product or installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

Comment: I'd love to report the problem that way, if it worked.:Disconnected from Visual Studio
Disconnected from Visual Studio
Oops, we have lost the connection to Visual Studio.

You have two choices:
Relaunch this page from Visual Studio. This is required if you want to report new feedback for Visual Studio.
Launch this page without Visual Studio. You would still be able to do everything else except report new feedback for Visual Studio. Click the button below to do that.

Comment: do you have any referenced files in the bin folder? Or can you freely delete the bin folder, and compile? I also recommend you try running VS as admin, and I quite much have always launched VS that way (as admin).  The other issue that often arises is if I launch the program using ctrl-f5 (non debug), since then the program is still running, and thus of course compile can't work since if the code/program is running, then dll's are locked.  But, I would shut down vs, delete the bin folder, and then try running vs as admin and see if that helps. Also, do you have any post-build settings?

Comment: @Albert I have no reference files in the .bin folder nor post-build settings.  I do not use ctrl-F5.  I deleted the bin folder to no avail, but I'm now running as admin and the problem has not repeated so far.  Thanks!